# How to load FLTK graphics toolkit in GNU Octave 3.8?

Tags: octave, fltk

I have installed GNU Octave 3.6.4 and 3.8.1 versions on one machine (OpenSUSE Linux 13.1, x86-64). Version 3.6.4 was out of the box, version 3.8.1 I build by myself from sources (configure-make-make install).

In octave-3.6.4 I have such output:

```
octave-3.6.4> available_graphics_toolkits
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = fltk
  [1,2] = gnuplot
}
octave-3.6.4> loaded_graphics_toolkits
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = fltk
}
```

In octave-3.8.1 I have gnuplot only:

```
octave-3.8.1> available_graphics_toolkits
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = gnuplot
}
octave-3.8.1> loaded_graphics_toolkits
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = gnuplot
}
```

**How can I load the FLTK graphics toolkit?**
I try so:

```
octave-3.8.1> register_graphics_toolkit("fltk")
octave-3.8.1> available_graphics_toolkits
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = fltk
  [1,2] = gnuplot
}
octave-3.8.1> graphics_toolkit("fltk")
error: __init_fltk__: not available without OpenGL and FLTK libraries
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/share/octave/3.8.1/m/plot/util/graphics_toolkit.m at line 74, column 5
```

Why FLTK properly loads in octave-3.6.4 but doesn't in octave-3.8.1? How can I connect octave-3.8.1 to OpenGL and FLTK libraries?

Comment: I suspect that you have missed some libraries (i.e. FLTK) during Octave 3.8 compilation.

Comment: @juliohm , you're right. I've missing some packages, it's need to be more attentive to ./configure output. Now it's ok.

Comment: I always wondered why Octave people do not statically link FLTK... It would save people from all the headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you see if you execute

```
octave_config_info().GRAPHICS_LIBS
```

in your 3.8.1 build? It should return something like

```
ans = -lfltk_gl -lfltk -lX11
```

If not then configure wasn't able to find your fltk dev libs. See config.log why. Most probably because you haven't installed them.

Comment: You're right. I've missing some packages, it's need to be more attentive to ./configure output. Now it's ok.

    `ans = -L/usr/lib64 -lfltk_gl -lGL -lfltk`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use latest stable version of Octave, use [Science repository](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/science/octave), or see details in [Octave wiki page](http://wiki.octave.org/OpenSUSE). FLTK is used by default in this packages. In the case of own build, be careful, you can lose some functions.